# How can I calculate the size of MFT for a given amount of files?

Tags: file, filesystems, ntfs, ntfs-mft

I have this exercise to do:

I am given an empty harddrive, with a sector-size of 512KB.
Now, each cluster would have 2 sectors, so

```
2*512 = 1024 Byte
```

For NTFS I am pretty sure I would have to calculate the MFT table size.

Sadly I can not find any resource on how to do that, or at least how to calculate the size of MFT entries. I know how to do it with FAT32, but I have no idea on NTFS.

Is there any way I could find some advice here?

Comment: It's not that simple. You can't calculate size of MFT for a given amount of files. One file can span across several File Records - to be specific: in NTFS, each file requires one or more MFT entries.

Comment: Any idea what I could do with this exercise then? Sadly, I don't have any file size given.

Comment: Please try to be more specific what you'd like to achieve. If the question is how you can calculate MFT size based on amount of files, the correct answer is you can't; it's the same as if you have 1000 bytes of UTF-8 text, you can't say how many characters that file contains based on file size (you'd have to parse it).

Comment: According to my exercise sheet I am supposed to calculate the size the file organisation would use on my hard drive. For FAT that would be the Table size. But I would like to calculate this value for NTFS now.

Comment: Ok - in that case you can't. Without more data you even can't count how many - if any - cluster would certain file occupy, even that depends on whether the file is sparse file, whether it's small file, so $DATA attribute fits into MFT... Size of MFT depends on so many variables - file size, file fragmentation (= size of $DATA attribute), # of hard links to that file... Check MSDN, or go to http://ntfs.com